# How to create an patch request with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

```js
axios.post('/api/v1/users',
            { "edited_field": "email", "email": email },
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': crsfToken }, }
        ).then((response) => {
            // Code
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Code
        })
```

I have this post method, but i want to create an patch method of this. i have seen some solutions where they post a form with an input value='patch' but since im not using a form i have no idea how it must be done.

Any help is welcome :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the **axios.patch(url[, data[, config]])** method referenced in the [Axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Axios has a built-in patch method. You can modify the code you currently have by replacing `axios.post` with `axios.patch`

```js
axios.patch('/api/v1/users',
            { "edited_field": "email", "email": email },
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': crsfToken }, }
        ).then((response) => {
            // Code
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Code
        })
```